# Декорирование итераторов или генераторов

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

Есть несколько таких методов

```
async def list(self, provider:int):
    await self.database.connect_async()
    for row in models.accounts.Account.select().where(Account.provider == provider & Account.deleted == False).execute():
        yield row
    self.database.close()
```

Хотелось бы вынести в декоратор подключение и отключение, но так как это генератор, то внутренняя часть декоратора его вернет сразу.

База это пул peewee:
    `database = peewee_asyncext.PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase()`

```
@dbdecor
async def list(self, provider:int):
    return models.accounts.Account.select().where(Account.provider == provider & Account.deleted == False).execute()
```

или

```
async def list(self, provider:int):
    return dbdecor(models.accounts.Account.select().where(Account.provider == provider & Account.deleted == False).execute())
```

Comment: Вопрос, в том, возможно ли вынести часть действий в декоратор без полного перебора исходного и создания нового генератора? В генераторе генераторов по идее не происходит вычисление включаемых - `(z**2 for z in (x for x in [1,2,3]))` Тогда достаточно чтобы ваши функция и декоратор возвращали генераторы.

Comment: хотел обойтись без перебора. дело в том что такой декоратор будет получать строчку с курсора до того как я буду готов её принять. сейчас думаю через context manager сделать. так можно будет оборачивать и генераторы и функции

Comment: `with`, чтобы вынести подключение к базе из методов уместен... обычно к базе подключение прописывают один раз в главной функции (app), посмотрите как это реализовано например здесь (https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/blog/blog.py).